# Adaptive Column in XAML UI

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I am trying to make an adaptive UI for Windows Universal Platform. I currently have a Visual State Manager that shows user control when the width is larger than 720. In outer grid I have 2 equal columns. In one column I have a Listview and in the other one I have a user control that shows details. How can I make the second column disappear when the width is smaller than 720? All helps are greatly appriciated. Here is a sample.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="DetailsPage.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <ListView Name="lvElements">
    </ListView>

    <local:UCDetails Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="DetailsPage" Grid.Column="1" />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a name to your columns:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DetailColumn" Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MasterColumn" Width="336"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Then, change simply the Width.

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Small">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MasterColumn.(Width)" Value="0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Medium">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the second column to 0 whenever the global width is less than 720 using a new visual state. Here is an example :

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DetailColumn" Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="DetailsPage.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="DetailColumn.(Width)" Value="0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <ListView Name="lvElements">
    </ListView>

    <local:UCDetails Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="DetailsPage" Grid.Column="1" />

</Grid>
```